# When can desulfation extend the life of a battery?

Tags: battery, maintenance

So I was reading up about [battery desulfation](https://www.batterystuff.com/kb/articles/charging-articles/make-the-bad-sulfation-go-away.html), and it seems like a promising way to rejuvenate lead-acid batteries.

### Questions

- Can this work on a severely discharged battery, e.g. less than 9 V for a 12 V battery?
- Can desulfation work on batteries that have been discharged for months or years?
- How frequently should the desulfation cycle be performed? Is there such a thing as too much desulfation?

Answer (score 1):

From reading that link, it's hard to say what's marketing and what's solid science.

I don't understand a lot about sulfaction (and I will read into it more and update as applicable), but from the sound of it you couldn't really use their device *too much*... that's not to say that the desulfaction process can't be done wrongly. The main risk would be in overcharging the cells if you're using what they show which is a charger/maintainer. However, if the charger is smart enough to shut off at full charge then it's fine. Just like leaving your phone on the charger *(modern cell phones at least)* doesn't cause the battery to explode. The intelligent components stop at full charge.

If their device acts the same, then you could use it daily without risk.

That said - they do offer a really good guarantee and warranty, which means that the will have explicit instructions that work best/safest. Depending on those instructions, you'll have the optimum usage for that device.

Anyway, again I'll update my answer if I learn new, more correct/applicable data.

As a note, this also may be worth asking and/or linking on the Chemistry stack or others.